# Referencing files minified by Web Essentials in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, minify, web-essentials

I have minified CSS and JS files that are auto-generated by Web Essentials, and auto-updated every time I update and save the original files.

What would be the best way to automatically toggle the actual (script/import) references within HTML between original (in Dev/Test) and minified (in Production) files?

This is within an MVC ASP.NET web app.

One idea would be to have server-side tags that render either ".min" or empty string based on an environment variable.  But I'm wondering if there's a better, smarter, easier, more efficient way of handling this.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

My style bundle is defined like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site{version}.css"));
```

And I reference it like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

However, this renders the following:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

It works fine if I take "{version}" out of bundle definition, but renders an empty "v=" if I include "{version}".

**Update 2:**

I just realized that due to certain complexities of the application, I can't use the bundling solution. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Bundling will help you in this instance. You should already be able to see an example in your BundleConfig.cs file in App_Start.

Here is a tutorial on how to conifgure it http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

From that tutorial, this is how you actually configure the bundles themselves, the files that will be in them, etc. This includes any jquery in the scripts folder into a bundle called `~/bundles/jquery`.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; // <-- this line overrides the debug check to show you the minified version even in debug mode... remove it for normal .min in debug/un-minned when not in debug behaviour
}
```

You then reference these from your views using

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

This will then render a script tag with the `.min` version of the jquery if you're not in debug or leave it out if you are. There needs to be a `.min` version and an un-minified version in the same scripts folder (which you should have if Web Essentials is creating the `.min` for you.

You could actually stop using Web Essentials to do the minification if you use ScriptBundles as they will minify the javascript for you when it packages it into the bundle.

***For your update***

The `"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"` means match any file in the scripts folder that starts with `jquery-` and ends with `.js` and has some version number between. If the files don't have a version number in them, then don't try and use the `{version}` substitution.

They do it with jquery in this case so that if you upgrade the version of jquery that you are using, you don't have to go back into your BundleConfig and manually change the file name for your jquery reference.

If your file was named `site1.3.7.css`, then this would probably work.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
                   .Include("~/Content/site{version}.css"));
```

but it sounds more likely that you just need `site.css`.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
                   .Include("~/Content/site.css"));
```

I'm not sure what you think prevents you from using them but you can link to files in CDNs and minify or not minify. Even just have individual files in a bundle to get the benefit of minification outside of debug without "bundling" them. So there's probably a way.

Comment: You're talking about the "{version}" piece?

Comment: Yes, amongst other things. That just says take any version of jquery.

Comment: You can also use this for the CSS minfication too, btw... just use a `StyleBundle()` instead. If you ever want to include something without minifying it I think there's a plain `Bundle()` too which just includes several files in the same output file without minifying.

Comment: I just realized that due to certain complexities of the application, I can't use the bundling solution.

Comment: What's stopping you from using it? As for `{version}` you don't need to use it if your files don't contain a version number, it's only for when you might update a library at some point in the future, like jQuery, where you don't want to have to manually go into the BundleConfig and change it every time you download a new version.

Comment: I don't really need to specify a version number for my site.css file. I just want to reference site.css vs site.min.css automatically.  So I don't can't get that workin.

Comment: My last example should do that, it will only do it when `EnableOptimizations` is manually set like my first code example from the tutorial and/or when you don't have the `<compilation debug="true" />` set in your web.config. The tutorial describes all this.